# Javascript nested ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I'm missing something if someone can please explain it to me. I'm trying to re-write existing code into the ternary operator way. 
I'm getting the following console error :

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

which I understand there's a condition not properly formatted which I can't seem to find. So I'm not sure what I'm missing or if I maybe misunderstand something in the filter function? Isn't the ? item.verified === true not suppose to automatically return the objects that's true?

```
var engagement = "social";
var audience = [{ 'verified': true, 'name': 'Steve'},
                { 'verified': false, 'name': 'Phil'},
                { 'verified': true, 'name': 'Jason'}];
let data = [];

data = audience.filter((item) => {
    (engagement === "social") 
    ? item.verified === true
    : (engagement === 'social-crm') 
    ? item.verified === false 
    : (engagement === 'all')
    ? item
})
```

The syntax that I understand:

```
data = audience.filter((item) => {
              if (this.engagement === 'social-crm') {
                return item.verified === true;
              } else if (this.engagement === 'social') {
                return item.verified === false;
              } else if (this.engagement === 'all') {
                return item;
              }
});
```

Here's the fiddle I've been trying to play around with: 
https://jsfiddle.net/phfilly/ya73e325/7/

Comment: "I'm trying to re-write existing code into the ternary operator way." — Don't. As you have noticed, it is hard to understand. Don't make more work for whomever has to maintain your code. They'll hate you for it. That person is likely to be you but 6 months older.

Comment: Thanks, I understand and feel the same way. However company wants to incorporate standards and told me to change it #death

Comment: Can you change to this 
data = audience.filter((item) => (engagement === "social") ? item.verified === true : (engagement === 'social-crm') ? item.verified === false : (engagement === 'all')? item : null)

Comment: @RobG so in the else I want to return the whole object again. Does that make sense?

Comment: A `filter` function expects a truthy or falsey return value. Returning `true` or `item` produces the same result. @Quentin best comment ever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. Your syntax isn't right. To understand why your code isn't working, it would help if you were to re-write your `if-else` statements a bit.

```
if (this.engagement === 'social-crm') {
    return item.verified === true;
} else if (this.engagement === 'social') {
    return item.verified === false;
} else if (this.engagement === 'all') {
    return item;
}
```

To this:

```
if(this.engagement === 'social-crm') { return item.verified === true; }
else {
   if(this.engagement === 'social') {item.verified === false; }
   else {
       if(this.engagement === 'all') {return item;} 
   }
}
```

Now, ternary operators follow a similar nested fashion.

```
cond1 ? val1 : ( val2 )
```

Where `val2 => cond2 ? val3 : (val4)`

Where `val4 => cond3 ? val5 : val6`

So, now you can rewrite your expression like this:

```
this.engagement === 'social-crm' ? item.verified === true : 
    (this.engagement === 'social' ? item.verified === false : 
        (this.engagement === 'all' ?  item : null))
```

The parenthesis matters here, because it closely mimics the nested if-elses from above.

Also note that for the inner most expression, a return value in the else *must* be specified. I've set it to null but you can return what you want. Do note this is the actual reason your code was failing. Apologies if the answer was long but I wanted to help you understand nested ternary operators.

Answer (score 2):

A nested ternary operator looks like this:

```
something = condition ? nested_condition ? value_if_both_conditions_are_true
    : value_if_nested_condition_is_false : value_if_condition_is_false;
```

This works even without parentheses, but as others have mentioned, it can be hard to read. Especially when multiple conditions are checked, by use of `&&` or `||` in the condition parts of this example.

Comment: It would be nice to include what happens if they are both false.

Comment: In this example, if both are false, the result is the same as when only the first condition is false

Answer (score 1):

A ternary operator looks like this:

```
something = (condition) ? a_value : a_different_value;
```

You forgot `: a_different_value` on the last case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You have to have a Condition for the Ternary operator as pointed by @Quentin

```
data = audience.filter((item) => { (engagement === "social") ? 
item.verified === true : (engagement === 'social-crm') ? 
item.verified === false : (engagement === 'all')? 
item : null})
```

Answer (score -2):

Deep nesting can write in a simpler way like this for ternary if-else

```js
let userName = 'Amoos'
let isStudent = false
let age = 7


userName 
      ? console.log(`User name: ${userName} `) 
      : console.log('Unknow user');
      isStudent ? console.log("Yes, is student ‍") 
                : console.log('No, not a student ‍');
                (age<18) ? console.log("Younger ")
                         : console.log("Elder ")
```