# How we can ignore some space in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I did this code :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('input.txt', 'utf8');

str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function (s) {
    return console.log(
    s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy'
        : s === 'alicia'
        ? 'girl'
        : s === 'cookie'
        ? 'dog'
        : 'unknown');
});
```

But in my input file there are some space, and I don't want my code to take it into account. My input file is :

```
cat
bob
alicia
shirley
cookie


thomas
rat`
```

So how can I code, to ignore the space in my input file please ?

Comment: Your `.split(/\s+/)` looks to be properly ignoring the empty newlines - the resulting array only contains the actual words?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove ALL white spaces from text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623231/remove-all-white-spaces-from-text)

Comment: `str.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/) ....` Clean your string before split

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was also thinking, but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Ternary operators aren't nested in this way. [See the proper nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716426/not-understanding-nested-ternary-operator)

Comment: @JuanCaicedo your solution doesn't work well sorry, I tried and between `cookie` and `thomas` there are space, and the code write `unknown`. The result is `unknown boy girl unknown dog unknown unknown unknown
`   so after rat the code take care about the space

Comment: it works for me `console.log(str.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm,"").split(/\s+/))`

Comment: Excuse me @JuanCaicedo , the mistake came from me, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the code below

```
function removeEmptyLines(str) {
  const arrayOfLines = str.split("\n"); // Remove empty lines from the string which leaves "" in the returned array
  const filtered = arrayOfLines.filter(line => line !== ""); // filter the array and remove all the empty strings
  const joined = filtered.join(" "); // form a single string
  return joined; // return filtered array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you'd `console.log(str.split(/\s+/))` you'll get

```
[ 'cat', 'bob', 'alicia', 'shirley', 'cookie', 'thomas', 'rat`' ]
```

so as everyone has already said `/\s+/` will in fact remove the spaces

> *@JuanCaicedo your solution doesn't work well sorry, I tried and between cookie and thomas there are space, and the code write unknown. The result is unknown boy girl unknown dog unknown unknown unknown so after rat the code take care about the space*

the output you're seeing is correct, according to your logic

```
s === 'bob'
        ? 'boy'
        : s === 'alicia'
        ? 'girl'
        : s === 'cookie'
        ? 'dog'
        : 'unknown');
```

If the string doesn't equal `bob` or `alicia` or `cookie` it will output unknown therefore

```
cat = unknown
bob = boy
alicia = girl
shirley = unknown
cookie = dog
thomas = unknown
rat` = unknown
```