# Toggle between three different classes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle between three different classes.
When each "button" is selected it then creates a row and displays information and hides any information displayed by a different toggle.

I have tried many different ways of adding the third class but am getting an error at `: 'toggle-misc';`:

> uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

I have looked all over online and cannot find a solution that doesn't include toggling with the same button or in a sequence.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.logins-toggle').on('click', function() {

    var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer') ? 'toggle-dealer' : 'toggle-portal': 'toggle-misc';
    var rowClass = toggleClass === 'toggle-dealer' ? 'row-dealer' : 'row-portal': 'row-misc';

    // Hide all elements with "row-" class and show the corresponding one
    $('.row-dealer, .row-portal, .row-misc').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass(rowClass)) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });

    // Remove or add 'is-active' class to the clicked toggle element
    $('.logins-toggle').removeClass('is-active');
    $(this).addClass('is-active');
  });

  // Automatically trigger a click on the first "logins-toggle" element
  $('.logins-toggle:first').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- sample HTML here, please -->
```

Comment: I've not seen `... ? ... : ... :` syntax before. How is that supposed to work? I think you would need another "?" in there, but it's probably best to just use a regular if/elseif/else statement for readability.

Comment: 1) That's not how a ternary works. 2) Please add the relevant HTML and CSS to the question so we can see a working example of the problem

Comment: @Paul not quite. It's almost a ternary expression, but the OP has added an invalid third case. Unless someone has come up with a new form of 'trinary' logic, I don't think it's going to work.

Comment: It looks like you have made a mistake trying to use nested ternarys. Consider looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44716426/javascript-nested-ternary-operator

Comment: You all are probably right!! I have never used a nested Ternary before. 
To convert this to a normal if/elseif/else statement would it look something like 
if ($(this) == 'toggle-dealer') {
          var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer')
        } else if ($(this) == 'toggle-portal'){
          var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer');
         } else if ($(this) == 'toggle-misc'){
          var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('toggle-misc');
        }

Comment: Don't dump code in a comment. That's not helpful. Please put your code and some HTML in a demo using the editor.

Comment: "*cannot find a solution that doesn't include toggling .. in a sequence.*" - because that's the solution you need here.

Comment: Look  here: [Ternary op Conditional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator#conditional_chains)

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is a short expression variant of a normal if/else-statement. You cannot have two `else` statements.

When written as a normal if/else-statement the issue might become more clear.

```js
var toggleClass = $(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer')
                ? 'toggle-dealer'
                : 'toggle-portal'
                : 'toggle-misc';

// could also be written as

if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer')) {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-dealer";
} else {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-portal";
} else {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-misc";
}
```

The above is syntactically incorrect and will throw an error, just like your double `:` (*else*) does.

To solve this you can either use an `else if`:

```js
if ($(this).hasClass('toggle-dealer')) {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-dealer";
  var rowClass = "row-dealer";
} else if ($(this).hasClass("toggle-portal")) {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-portal";
  var rowClass = "row-portal";
} else {
  var toggleClass = "toggle-misc";
  var rowClass = "row-misc";
}
```

Or instead of checking each class manually, you could define an array. Use it to iterate through the options, and find the one that matches.

```js
const classParts = ["dealer", "portal", "misc"];

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  
    $('.logins-toggle').on('click', function () {
        const classPart = classParts.find(part => $(this).hasClass(`toggle-${part}`))
                       || "misc"; // default to "misc" if non matches
        
        const toggleClass = `toggle-${classPart}`;
        const rowClass    = `row-${classPart}`;
        
        // Hide all elements with "row-" class and show the corresponding one
        const selector = classParts.map(part => `.row-${part}`).join(", ");
        $(selector).each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass(rowClass)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        
        // Remove or add 'is-active' class to the clicked toggle element
        $('.logins-toggle').removeClass('is-active');
        $(this).addClass('is-active');
    });
  
    // Automatically trigger a click on the first "logins-toggle" element
    $('.logins-toggle:first').click();
});
```